# Why does the router block containers connection in docker?

Tags: networking, router, docker

I have a problem with a docker environment: I was able to clone it and build it, but once I ran `docker-compose up`, one of the services (let's call it A) couldn't start because it couldn't reach its dependency service (let's call it B):

```
serviceA   | 2021/05/06 22:14:25 Problem with dial: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: getsockopt: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
serviceA   | 2021/05/06 22:14:25 Timeout after 30s waiting on dependencies to become available: [tcp://serviceB:5432]
```

During one of my latest test, the router turned off because of a power outage, so I had no internet... and, all of a sudden, the services started properly! I then tried again to run `docker-compose up` while turning the wifi on and off, and I can safely say that when I'm offline the problem disappears.

Has it ever happened to anyone before? Networking is not my field of expertise, so I'd like to understand why it happens - and how to solve it once and for all: so far, the only solution I've found is to turn off the wifi when I run `docker-compose up/run`...

I'm working on Ubuntu 20.04, Docker version is 20.10.6.
The router is a TIM Hub Technicolor AGHP and, as long as I know, there is no port forwarding rule defined within it.

PS: please, feel free to ask for any detail I may have left out: as I said, networking is not my field of expertise, so I simply don't know what can be useful or not...

UPDATE 1: I did the same steps on another computer, running Ubuntu 18.04 and Docker 20.10.6, same behaviour.

UPDATE 2: using another connection instead of my home router's connection, services went up as expected.

Comment: Something is misconfigured in the container, as `localhost` [loopback IP `127.0.0.1`] is never routed outside its local machine, unless a port redirect is configured on the local machine, since it's not a valid routable IP outside of a local machine. _(Most likely reason for the error is a program/service already has port `5432` open)_

Comment: @JW0914 is there anything I could do to inspect the issue? Like, what would I have to do in order to find out if any program/service is already using port 5432, or how to check for any port redirect?

Comment: You'd use a program to list open sockets, such as `netstat -a`

Comment: @JW0914 couldn't find anything referring to 5432 in the table returned by it